Answers containing contact details
I found some answers containing contact details, such as email addresses. What are the moderation rules for them?
Example 1

Most other SE sites simply treat such answers as spam.

The answer is a support representative for one of the plugins that the original question is using. They left their email address in the answer, asking OP to contact them.
While this may be viewed as good-intentioned support, it goes against our guidelines on what constitutes an answer. Furthermore, it's always better to go to the plugin source website directly for support instead of someone's posted email address. This is for legitimacy, to protect yourself from any malicious users.
